# While clicking search,my application has stopped

Tags: java, android

I am using searching,to show the listview contents.While clicking the search functionality or type any data,it shows that my application has stopped.

Mainactivity.java

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       private void fillData(Cursor projectsCursor) {
           //mDbHelper.open();   

           if(projectsCursor!=null)
           {
           String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT};
           int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text2, R.id.text1, R.id.count};
            dataAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
             this, R.layout.activity_row, 
             projectsCursor, 
             from, 
             to,
             0);
            setListAdapter(dataAdapter);

            EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
              myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               }

               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                 int count, int after) {
               }

               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                 int before, int count) {
                   dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
               }
              });

              dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                     public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                         return mDbHelper.fetchProjectByName(constraint.toString());
                     }
                 });
```

This is my db.java

```
 public Cursor fetchProjectByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
          Log.w(TAG, inputText);
          Cursor mCursor = null;
          if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
           mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, new String[] {CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID,
                 CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT}, 
             null, null, null, null, null);

          }
          else {
           mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, new String[] {CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID,
                 CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT}, 
                CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
             null, null, null, null);
          }
          if (mCursor != null) {
           mCursor.moveToFirst();
          }
          return mCursor;

         }
```

Using the db in fetchproject by name i want to search the contents of the listview which will match according to my search option.It shows some logcaterror.
While typing or clicking the search area,it shows my applicaton has stopped.

this is my logcat error.

```
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'title' does not exist
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:333)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:345)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.changeCursor(CursorAdapter.java:309)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at android.widget.CursorFilter.publishResults(CursorFilter.java:67)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-15 12:23:08.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25812):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: In your query add CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE in the projection

Comment: where dude,where i have to add

Comment: @Tarun http://pastebin.com/jb1BA94g here i paste my full code,where i have to add dude

Comment: @Tarun what i have to add dude

Comment: In fetchProjectByName

Comment: @Tarun what line i have to add dude,kindly make your answer dude

Comment: @Tarun place your answer

Comment: Line 107, 113 add title column

Comment: @KarthickM: Get into the habit of reading what the LogCat says. In this case, it spelt it out for you: `column 'title' does not exist`

Comment: @Tarun thanks for giving answer accept my question also dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add title column in your query.

```
mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, 
new String[]{CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID,CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE,
CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT}, 
null, null, null, null, null);
```